# Tableview and Detail view displayed at once without splitviewcontroller

Tags: view, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to find a way to display a tableview and a detail view inside of a single view controller, and have the detail view update its contents based on which tableview cell is selected.

This is exactly what a UISplitViewController does; however, I am looking for a completely custom interface that I cannot accomplish with the cookie cutter SVC.

Basically I have a single view that has a small tableview on the left (it doesn't fill the entire height of the screen, so its a custom size) and then a detail view on the right.

I have tried a couple way of doing this, such as programmatically creating the table, using view controller containers, etc.

I only want to change the text and images that show up in the detail view when a new cell is tapped, not push a new detail view.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!